# Restrict consecutive characters using Java Regex

Tags: java, regex

I need to allow alphanumeric characters , `"?","." , "/"` and `"-"` in the given string. But I need to restrict consecutive `-` only.

For example:

1. www.google.com/flights-usa should be valid
2. www.google.com/flights--usa should be invalid

currently I'm using `^[a-zA-Z0-9\\/\\.\\?\\_\\-]+$`.

Please suggest me how to restrict consecutive `-` only.

Comment: Do you have to use a single regular expression?  Why not just `s.matches("[-?./a-zA-Z0-9]+") && !s.contains("--")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use grouping with quantifiers:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9/.?_]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9/.?_]+)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lV0tE8/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9/.?_]+` - 1 or more characters from the set defined in the character class (can be replaced with `[\w/.?]+`)
- `(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9/.?_]+)*` - zero or more sequences (`(?:...)*`) of:

  - `-` - hyphen
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9/.?_]+` - see above
- `$` - end of string.

Or use a negative lookahead:

```
^(?!.*--)[a-zA-Z0-9/.?_-]+$
 ^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/lV0tE8/2)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*--)` - a negative lookahead that will fail the match once the regex engine finds a `--` substring after any 0+ chars other than a newline
- `[a-zA-Z0-9/.?_-]+` - 1 or more chars from the set defined in the character class
- `$` - end of string.

**Note** that `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` = `\w` if you do not use the `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` flag. So, the first would look like `"^[\\w/.?]+(?:-[\\w/.?]+)*$"` and the second as `"^(?!.*--)[\\w/.?-]+$"`.

Comment: Just FYI: inside a character class, there is no need to escape all non-word chars. The `/` is not a special character at all, the hyphen does not have to be escaped at the end of the character class, the dot and `?` inside a  character class lose their special meaning, and `_` is a word character

Comment: The only regex that works from above is this one `^(?!.*--)[a-zA-Z0-9/.?_-]+$`

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to restrict multiple dashes with negative look-behind on a dash, like this:

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\/\.\?\_]|(?<!-)-)+$
```

The right side of the `|`, i.e. `(?<!-)-`, means "a dash, unless preceded by another dash".

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/cY2vO0/1)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the efficiency of this, but I believe this should work.

`^([a-zA-Z0-9\/\.\?\_]|\-([^\-]|$))+$`

For each character, this regex checks if it can match `[a-zA-Z0-9\/\.\?\_]`, which is everything you included in your regex except the hyphen. If that does not match, it instead tries to match `\-([^\-]|$)`, which matches a hyphen not followed by another hyphen, or a hyphen at the end of the string.

[Here's a demo.](https://regex101.com/r/fL1cD0/1)